# How to combine the keys in the Triple Diffie-Hellman (3DH) key exchange?

Tags: diffie-hellman

I was reading up on the Triple Diffie-Hellman (3-DH) key exchange and noticed that the wikipedia description [1] is different from the the original protocol definition [2] and the modified definition [3] they reference.

Two users have two key pairs each; $a, A$ and $x, X$ for one user and $b, B$ and $y, Y$ for the other. $H$ is a key derivation function. Is there any difference between the following two shared secrets that can be derived?

- $K = H(Ay, Xb) = H(Ya, Bx)$
- $K = H(Yx, Bx, Ya) = H(Xy, Xb, Ay)$

The difference being the addition of the $Yx = Xy$ values to the key derivation.

References:

1. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Triple_Diffie-Hellman_(3-DH))
2. [Original definition](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=622d30dae8ad0d4d31ec2b3312d7889db3266306) page 15
3. [Modified definition](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/11593447_30.pdf) page 560-561